# how to get value from textarea ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ckeditor4.x

I am new to ckeditor, at moment I am writting a demo code on ckeditor. Could someone please help me how to get value from texterea ckeditor. Here below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor 4</title>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="idDemo" name="demo"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Get Data" onclick="myFunction()" />
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var content = $('idDemo').val();
            alert(content);
        }
    </script>

    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>CKEDITOR.replace('demo');</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_savedata.html), this should do the trick.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor 4</title>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="idDemo" name="demo"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Get Data" onclick="myFunction()" />
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var content= CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
            alert(content);
        }
    </script>

    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>CKEDITOR.replace('demo');</script>
</body>

</html>
```